# How to execute function in handelbars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I started working on some project with handlebars and expressjs. And during my trip I spot one issue. When I am creating a new template in hbs like:

**login.hbs**

```
<div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="enter email"/>
    <button>Do something with email</button>
</div>
```

And also I got **login.js** with that code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {});
});
module.exports = router;
```

So now I'm just thinking, how can I add "click" event for the button and also get value from input to do something with it?

Was trying to do `document.getElementById(...)` but I receive "document is not defined".

Also I just want to split logic (do not put everything in . tag) - just split logic to diff files to be consistent.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just add it to your handlebars template the same way you would normally do it in HTML. If you want to split javascript logic and HTML presentation just do it the normal way, add `<script src="your-frontend-js-file.js"></script>` to **login.hbs**. It's just an HTML string, nothing special. It's not a dynamic object like React.js or Angular.js

Comment: I think you need to make sure you understand the difference between which code is executed on the client and which on the server.